# filter out a substring from a string in linux only once

Tags: linux, sed, substring

I am trying to extract a particular substring from a string that I have using sed command in linux. However, the issue is that after the command has returned me the substring the first time, I again looks for the starting keyword in the string.

I want to skip the last part. I just want the first substring between the keywords.

String: **bhaskar.txt**

```
bhaskar
rahul
gaurav
ganesh
bhaskar
rahul
```

Substring required: ***Everything between "bhaskar" and "ganesh"***

Command used: `sed -n '/bhaskar/,/ganesh/p' bhaskar.txt`

output:

```
bhaskar
rahul
gaurav
ganesh
bhaskar
rahul
```

Expected Output:

```
bhaskar
rahul
gaurav
ganesh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you could do it in awk:

```
awk '/bhaskar/ && !p++, /ganesh/' bhaskar.txt
```

The first time `/bhaskar/` matches, `p` is not yet defined, so `!p` is true and the range begins. The `p++` means that after the value has been checked, increment `p` by 1. The range will continue until `/ganesh/` matches.

After the first range has completed, if `/bhaskar/` matches again, `p` will be positive, so `!p` will evaluate to false and the range will not restart.

Output:

```
bhaskar
rahul
gaurav
ganesh
```

---

Here's another way you could do it, that some may prefer:

```
awk '/bhaskar/ {p=1} p {print} /ganesh/ {exit}' bhaskar.txt
```

Arguably more self-explanatory, it sets a variable `p` as soon as `/bhaskar/` matches, prints when the variable `p` is set and exits (after printing) when `/ganesh/` matches.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -v a=bhaskar -v b=ganesh '$0 == a { p = 1; t = "" }; $0 == b && p { printf "%s%s\n", t, b; p = 0 }; p { t = t $0 ORS }' file
```

Output:

```
bhaskar
rahul
gaurav
ganesh
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed, you need to use a loop:

```
sed -n '/bhaskar/{: loop; p; /ganesh/q; n; b loop}' bhaskar.txt
```

---

Upon second thought, not so, you just need to quit at the end of the range:

```
sed -n '/bhaskar/,/ganesh/p; /ganesh/q'
```